# MongoDB transaction

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a method like below in C#:

```
private void Save(object)
{
   mongoCollection.Save(object);
   someotherRelationaldb.Save(object);
}
```

I have two DBs in which I have to save a object. One is MongoDB and another is a relational DB SQL server. If the Commit on Relational DB fails, I want to rollback the MongoDB save (I would like to maintain the order of save). What would be the proper way to rollback using the C# driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

Now possible.

For example Java;

```
try (ClientSession clientSession = client.startSession()) {
   clientSession.startTransaction();
   collection.insertOne(clientSession, docOne);
   collection.insertOne(clientSession, docTwo);
   clientSession.commitTransaction();
}
```

[See more about mongodb transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions)

Comment: Sorry but this is a  simple transaction between mongodb and mongodb (same mongo).

The question talk how to create a transaction between mongodb and another relational database.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.
The only way to do this would be to wrap `someotherRelationaldb.Save(object);` in a try catch, and on the catch, do `mongoCollection.Remove`

You'd probably need a known identifier property on `object` and could then do something like:

```
mongoCollection.Remove(Query.EQ("_id", object.Id));
```

So, rather untidily, your Save method would look a bit like:

```
private void Save(object)
{
   mongoCollection.Save(object);

   try
   {
      someotherRelationaldb.Save(object);
   }
   catch
   {
      mongoCollection.Remove(Query.EQ("_id", object.Id));
   }
}
```

Another way is to store a flag property on the `object` that get's updated **after** the successful write to `someOtherRelationaldb`

This isn't exactly ideal either, but you could modify your query to only return docs where `IsPersisted` flag is true.

Neither of these approaches will play nice in a heavily sharded environment though I wouldn't think.

Comment: thanks.. i thought so.. and my save could be either update or insert:)

Comment: in the case of an update, you might not want to remove the doc.. but revert it to the last version before the update? just something to keep in mind

Comment: @Alex, what happens if the server crashes after save throws an exception, but before the item is removed from MongoDB? Is there a more elegant way to approach this now (I notice your post is dated 2013).  +1.